# How do I take only numbers from a string?

Tags: c++, string, numbers

I need to copy numbers from a string to another string in c++. I wrote this code but it only copies the first number in the string.

```
class Number{
    private:
        string value;
    public:
        void Print(){
            cout<<value;
        }
        Number(string dgr){
            int i = 0; 
            for(int j=0; j<dgr.length();j++){
                if(isdigit(dgr[j])){
                    value[i]=dgr[j];
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: What is the input? What is the output? And can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? Also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And lastly, please don't add details as comments, *edit your question* instead.

Comment: What is `value`? Are you sure `value[i]` is in bounds?

Comment: Sorry this is my very first post. Basicaly I want a string from the user like "asd123asd" and copy that string's numeric characters into another string "123" for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you show, the string `value` is an *empty* string. That means all indexing into it will be *out of bounds* and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Instead *append* the characters to the string:

```
value += dgr[j];
```

Comment: Wow thanks but still have a problem. when I input "a6s54da65sd4a" it returns "6546541877994624". What's that "1877994624" part? When I recompile and run it the number won't change.

Comment: @FurkanBozkurt That should not happen with the code you show. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post a new question about that issue.

Answer (score 0):

operator [] in the string can be used to modify already existing characters. It does not extend the length of the string. So, if you pre-assign some value to 'value' you would see the characters modified there (up to the length of this string).

What you rally need is something like this:

```
value += dgr[j];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment but as a response to:
Wow thanks but still have a problem. when I input "a6s54da65sd4a" it returns "6546541877994624". What's that "1877994624" part? When I recompile and run it the number won't change.

I can't see the value being reset or initialized anywhere. What is the size of value?
I would use append instead of accessing various elements in "value". Something like value.append(1, dgr[j]);

Comment: I solved it. it seems method Print() returns a random value. when I add return -1; at the and that funny number changes to -1. But it's not a problem since I don't need to print the string. I wrote that just for control. Thanks anyway. Btw "value" defined in private. "...string value;.."